# git - merge big branch by one commit at a time

Tags: git

I have branch `test`. I want to merge it into `development`. `test` has a lot of commits. I'm afraid of possible conflicts, so I decided to merge by one commit at a time. I know I can use `git cherry-pick` to merge one commit into another branch (or some range of commits).

When `development` was N commits behind `test`, I tried to `cherry-pick` the oldest commit, pushed it to remote, then recognized that `development` is ahead of `test` by one commit. I expected that `development` would be behind by N-1 commits instead. I guess, with `cherry-pick` I'll mess up my git history.

How can I merge two branches with minimal risks of getting conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) that :

> Reapply commits on top of another base tip

It takes each commit and replay it.

Here is a more complete demonstration : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_msiOrYLgM